# how to make web application build independent of ant version

Tags: java, xml, linux, ant

I have developed a web application using Netbeans 7.0. Building(Generating a war file) works in netbeans but if I build the project on another server(linux) using `ant` I get the following:

```
[packwolf src]$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/packwolf/Application/src/build.xml:12: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/packwolf/Application/src/nbproject/build-impl.xml:22: Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Not doesn't support the nested "antversion" element.
```

when I checked the build-impl.xml, it has an XML block which checks for ANT version 1.7 or higher. How to make build independent of ant version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a feature is only supported in new version how do you propose to make it available in earlier version?

Comment: the recent ant version is 1.8.4. Really sure this version is for ant?

Answer (score 3):

A nested `antversion` task is allowed only 1.7 onwards so no way you can actually make this work with full functionality. This is what you can do as workaround though these are not solutions to the problem

1. Comment out the ANT check in the build-impl.xml. Then run on an older version of ANT (say 1.6.5). This would stop the `antversion` check and the build will progress but without seeing the build.xml its not possible to comment where else it might fail.
2. Install a newer version of ANT wherever the build is supposed to run.

Answer (score 1):

You could check in ant to repository and use it instead of default in OS. But to run ant you need java. You could check in JRE to you repository but in this case your repository will be really big.

Comment: I think this is not the best solution; executables should ideally be not checked in unless they are proprietary and change only in a years.

having said that, this is a solution nonetheless and I don't think checking in Java+Ant is so big as to be concerned as space is cheap and modern version control tools are good enough to handle hundreds of gigs

Comment: I agree that the best solution is to update ant on the build machine if it's required. But sometimes the solution about keeping ant in source control is useful also.